# Sometimes, "programming to interfaces" introduces possible (and avoidable) runtime exceptions?

Tags: java, interfaces

Please consider the *com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap*

Programming to its interface, *Map* , creates a bug that could blow-up in the runtime as such:

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = ImmutableMap.copyOf(justSomeMap);
myMap.put(key, val); // bang. runtime error.
```

In this case, the idea of "program to the interface, and don't worry about the implementing class" introduces a possible runtime bug.

The author of the *ImmutableMap* factory method recognized that and made the return type a class, not an interface. The methods that mutate *Map* were deprecated in **ImmutableMap** thus allowing the compiler to issue warnings.

- Is everything I said above correct?

Next, a new interface *ImmutableMapInterface* could have easily been created for the **ImmutableMap** class. *ImmutableMapInterface* would exactly be *Map* but just without the methods that would allow **ImmutableMap** to mutate. Were there *ImmutableMapInterface* , you can keep programming to interfaces.

So, why is there no *ImmutableMapInterface* ? I am going to guess the reason is just expediency. I agree. Creating an interface for *every* single class sounds a little too extreme. right?

Comment: Maybe Java hasn't considered it, but C# does have immutable interfaces.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez .net has its own goofiness like `System.Array` implementing `IList`

Comment: I think this is a case of legacy concerns putting you between a rock and a hard place rather than anything relating to interfaces. You would also be worse of if the generality of map was achieved through a common base class rather than a interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java does this in a few occasions and it is an *abomination unto man.*

This sort of thing is a textbook violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle, which leads to the sort of bugs you describe. **Well written code does not do that.**

You are right that making an interface for every single class is absurd. You need to use a little pragmatism in deciding what to make an interface for and what not to. The other thing to remember is that advice existed back in the C, C++ days. "Program to an interface" does not mean a literal `interface` in Java or C#. It works just as well with web apis or Internet protocols... Here an interface is a guaranteed/exposed behavior, not the underlying implementation.